# Mean.Js Multiple Layouts (After Login Layout and Before Login Layout)

Tags: javascript, node.js, yeoman, meanjs

I am using Mean.js

i want to use multiple layout. Is it possible to use for example layoutHome.server.view.html before user logins in and after user logs in i want to use layoutAdmin.server.view.html

At the moment we have just layout.server.view.html with items disabled before user logs in. I want to use completely different layout if user is not logged in.

I am quite new to Mean.Js, please excuse me if this is very easy one.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue with multiple layout. Did you find any solution?

Comment: This seems to be a question that a lot of people have, but no-one has an answer :(